# Stop animation if hover state

Tags: jquery

I have a footer animation that animates open, delays 5 seconds then animates close. I would like to stop the animation that closes if mouse if over the footer.

Here is the code:

```
if(jQuery('body').hasClass('page-template-template-home')){
    jQuery('footer').animate({
          'bottom': '0px'
    }, timein).addClass('footer-show').delay('5000');
    footeranimate();
    fix = true;
}
```

I need to stop `footeranimate()` if the footer is being hovered on, or else run the animate close.

Here is the  footeranimate function:

```
function footeranimate(){
    if (jQuery('footer').hasClass('footer-show')) {
        var footerHeight = jQuery('footer').outerHeight();
        jQuery('footer').animate({
            'bottom': '-' + footerHeight + 'px'
        }, timein).removeClass('footer-show');
        move_footer_up();
    } else {
        jQuery('footer').animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        }, timein).addClass('footer-show');
    }
}
```

The html:

```
 <footer>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="footer-shape">
    <div id="open-work">
        <span>Our Work</span>
    </div>
    <svg width='100%' viewBox="0,0 1600,900" preserveAspectRation="xMinYMin meet">
        <polygon fill="black" points="0,133 1600,0 1600,900 0,900"/>
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="inner-footer-feature">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-3">

</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">

</div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

</div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">

</div>



</div>
    </div>                  
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: You must be having some `html` for this, post that too... :)

Comment: Try using **[`.stop`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
var timein = 1000;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('footer').on('mousemove' , function(){
      if (!jQuery('footer').hasClass('footer-show')){
        jQuery('footer').stop().animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        }, timein).addClass('footer-show');
      }
  }).on('mouseout blur',function(){
      if (jQuery('footer').hasClass('footer-show')){
        var footerHeight = jQuery('footer').outerHeight() - 20;
        jQuery('footer').stop().animate({
            'bottom': '-' + footerHeight + 'px'
        }, timein).removeClass('footer-show');
        //move_footer_up();
      }
    
  });
});
```

```css
footer{
  height : 150px;
  background : #373737;
  position : absolute;
  bottom : -130px;
  width : 100%;
}
footer > div{
  color: #fff;
  text-align : right;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<footer>
  <div>Close</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks heaps for your help. I couldn't get this work but. Here is what my code looked like:

Comment: if(jQuery('body').hasClass('page-template-template-home')){

                   var StopIt = false;
    $('footer').on('mousemove' , function(){
      if(StopIt == false){
       footeranimate();
       StopIt = true;
      }
  }).on('mouseout blur',function(){
      if(StopIt == true){
       StopIt = false;
      }
    
  });

Comment: @AidenCole I updated my answer .. is this what you looking for??

Comment: Hey Mohamed, Sorry for slow reply. Thanks for the code. It actually works but I thing I didn't explain that well.

Comment: I didn't want the footer to open on hover if it was closed, just stay open if on hover. The footer animates up on scroll and doesn't need to be opened. Please see here:http://aidencole.com.au/percept/

Comment: I need to not run the animation: footeranimate() if on hover, else run footeranimate()...I think. Any help much appreciated